# Adding misc text values onto the get_info page of a public node

Tags: full-node, public-node

Public nodes have a get_info page like this: http://node.xmrbackb.one:28081/get_info

Is there a way to add in my own custom values? Say I wanted to add my monero address or an email to that list. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to add custom values would be to edit the source code and recompile. There are however good reasons why such a feature is *not* made easily available - fingerprinting. In fact, quite the *opposite* feature exists, a way of restricting what `get_info` divulges (restricted mode).

As a node operator one should want to share as little information as possible and for what information is shared, should not have unnecessary distinguishing marks. Monero aims to limit the mistakes users can unwittingly make in this regard, for example the addition of restricted mode mentioned above and the removal of unencrypted payment IDs.